# Accessing all variables declared in a function without duplicating code

Tags: python, function, variables, scope, return-value

Given:

```
PICKLE_FILENAME_INSTRUCTION_IDS = 'pickled_instruction_ids.txt'

def compare_instruction_id_list_with_baseline(baselineidspicklefile):
    baseline_ids = load_pickled_ids(baselineidspicklefile)
    current_main_url_content = get_page_content(main_url_test)
    root = lh.fromstring(current_main_url_content)
    current_ids = get_instruction_ids(root)
    diff = [id for id in current_ids if id not in baseline_ids]
    return diff
```

where `baselineidspicklefile` is the baseline of ids (a `list`), pickled.

Later on in the code, I do a check of `diff`, and if it's not empty, I do something with the new ids (`current_ids`). Now though, I realise that if diff is non-empty, I also wish to overwrite the baseline ids with the new list  of diffs via pickle, making it the new baseline.

`current_ids` is local to this function though. So I can't just call `pickle.dumps()` on it from the main section of the program. I'd rather not return both `diff` *and* `current_ids` from the function. And obviously I'd rather not make `current_ids` global.
What are my options for accessing both variables?

Note: This is a general issue I have - I also encounter it when using urllib2 e.g in a function that does the following:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
content = response.read()
```

I typically return `content` so I can do things like `lxml.html.fromstring(content)`, but then I realise that a later point in the program will need to access `response`, and I'm stuck because that's not what I've returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the builtin `locals()` function:

```
PICKLE_FILENAME_INSTRUCTION_IDS = 'pickled_instruction_ids.txt'

def compare_instruction_id_list_with_baseline(baselineidspicklefile):
    baseline_ids = load_pickled_ids(baselineidspicklefile)
    current_main_url_content = get_page_content(main_url_test)
    root = lh.fromstring(current_main_url_content)
    current_ids = get_instruction_ids(root)
    diff = [id for id in current_ids if id not in baseline_ids]
    return locals()
```

You can then use all variables defined in `compare_instruction_id_list_with_baseline` by using the return value and then in brackets a string that defines the variable you want.  For example, `return_value = compare_instruction_id_list_with_baseline(...)`  `diff = return_value['diff']`.

Comment: My problem was a box. You thought outside of that box and arrived at an elegant solution that I can apply universally. Thank you.